# JDBC ERROR: operator does not exist: date = integer

Tags: java, sql, postgresql, jdbc

```
    String checkAvailable_flight = String.format("SELECT Flightid, flightdate,"
            + " origin, destination FROM flight"
            + " WHERE  Flightdate::Date = %s  AND origin = %s"
            + " AND destination = %s;", date_, origin_, destination_);

    ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery(checkAvailable_flight);

    if (!rs.next()) {

        System.out.println("no data inserted");
    } else {

        do {
            int flightid = rs.getInt("flightid");
            String date = rs.getString("flightdate");
            String origin = rs.getString("origin");
            String destination = rs.getString("destination");

            System.out.printf("%-10d %5s %5s %7s\n",flightid, date, origin, destination);

        } while (rs.next());
    }
```

Error(s) occurred:

```
SQLException : ERROR: operator does not exist: date = integer
  Hint: No operator matches the given name and argument type(s). You might need to add explicit type casts.
  Position: 86
SQLState : 42883
SQLCode : 0
```

hello, i working on JDBC and wanna execute the sql query and print out the table ..but i got the error above..

i try to casting the flightdate in another way, like:

```
CAST(Flightdate AS TEXT) LIKE '2013-04-12%'
```

but the error still occurred....

any suggestion will appreciate it..

Comment: the flightdate which is the type of timestamp ...

Comment: Please read http://bobby-tables.com, http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection

Answer (score 15, accepted):

I'm guessing your dates are probably being substituted in without quoting, like `2012-01-01` instead of `'2012-01-01'`. `2012-01-01` is an integer mathematical expression that results in the number `2010`, so you're comparing a date to an integer. You need to quote your dates, or better, use proper prepared statements.

Why used prepared statements?

- It's easier to get right
- [lil' bobby tables](http://bobby-tables.com/)
- [Wikipedia: SQL Injection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection)

To demonstrate what I think your code's problem is, I think you're doing this:

```
regress=> SELECT DATE '2012-03-12' = 2012-03-12;
ERROR:  operator does not exist: date = integer
LINE 1: SELECT DATE '2012-03-12' = 2012-03-12;
                                 ^
HINT:  No operator matches the given name and argument type(s). You might need to add explicit type casts.
```

Observe:

```
regress=> \x
Expanded display is on.
regress=> SELECT 
              2012-03-12 AS unquoted,
              pg_typeof(2012-03-12) AS unquotedtype,
              '2012-03-12' AS quoted,
              pg_typeof('2012-03-12') AS quotedtype, 
              DATE '2012-03-12' AS typespecified,
              pg_typeof(DATE '2012-03-12') AS typespecifiedtype;
-[ RECORD 1 ]-----+-----------
unquoted          | 1997
unquotedtype      | integer
quoted            | 2012-03-12
quotedtype        | unknown
typespecified     | 2012-03-12
typespecifiedtype | date

(1 row)
```

If you won't use prepared statements, replace `%s` with `DATE '%s'`, but *please* use prepared statements.

Can you add a statement to print the contents of `checkAvailable_flight` after formatting, then paste its output here to confirm or refute my guess?